# Method element(int) is undefined for ArrayList<double>

Tags: java, arraylist, get, element

```
protected ArrayList<double[]> amostra = new ArrayList<double[]>();

public double[] element(int k){
    return amostra.get(k);

public static void main(String args[]){
        double k[]= {4,5,6};
        double k1[]= {0,0,0};
        double k2[] = {1,1,3};
        ArrayList<double[]> amostra = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        amostra.add(k);
        amostra.add(k1);
        amostra.add(k2);
        amostra.size();
        System.out.println(amostra.element(1));
```

So this is my code, I'm adding vectors to an arraylist amostra, and I wanted to print to the console the elements in position k, but when i try to do it i get the error
The method element(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is `amostra`? What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: you have to make your arrayList `amostra` static and make your `element` method static. Then call your `element` method like this
 `System.out.println(element(1));`

Comment: My previous comment assumes that you have these 2 things in the same class as your `main`

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html: do you see a method named element()? So, why are you surprised by this error message?

Comment: Yep that was the problem, I was defining methods for my class, and then was calling ArrayLists which don't have those methods defined, sorry I'm still new to this

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList does not have element(int) method. That's the message the compiler is sending to you. Use get(int x) instead, it will return the double **array** (not vector!), stored at the x position of the ArrayList:

```
int x;
double[] doubleArray = amostra.get(x);
```

if you want to access to an specific position of one of the arrays in the array list, you should use something like:

```
amostra.get(arrayListPosition)[doubleArrayPosition];
```

this last line will return a double.

Comment: That was the problem indeed, i was creating a class, and the method element was only defined for that class, not for ArrayLists!